# EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW when using Facebook SDK in Unity Android

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, opengl-es

I've integrated the Facebook Unity SDK to my Unity proyect and when I try to login in Android without the app installed my browser shows up, does something for about 1 second, closes and it throws the next error:

> EGL Unable to acquire context EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW a nativewindowtype argument does not refer to a valid native window.

It works on some devices and it fails in the rest. ( For example, it works on a Nexus 4 and Samsung galaxy S ( with stock android ) and it doesnt in a Samsung galaxy 5 with Touch Wiz )

Any ideas of what could trigger that?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what's wrong without more info. In all cases, what Unity version are you using? Unity 5? if so, are you using the [latest **beta** Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/beta/webgl)? The current stable version doesn't support Unity 5. Moreover, this might not be a Facebook SDK issue but might be a limitation in Unity. I would recommend you asking in answers.unity3d.com

Comment: I'm getting this error with the custom plugins I did that use the method UnitySendMessage ... works fine with iOS and fails silently with Android. I'm about to use a plain gameobject as opposed to a prefab/gameobject ... thats going to be painful if it proves to be a solution.  will revert in an hour or two

Comment: that did solve my problem (annoyingly) but I don't think it will help you. can you elaborate on how you are using Facebook Unity SDK exactly? cheers. The reason I think my solution wont help is I still see the BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW error.